# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Estou tentando inserir dados em uma tabela, porem não estou conseguindo, esta dando o seguinte erro: "Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.", alguém sabe como resolver?

Criei a seguinte tabela:

```
create table pessoas (
cpf int (11),
nome varchar(30) not null,
nascimento date,
endereco varchar(30) not null,
cep int(7),
bairro varchar(20),
cidade varchar(30),
uf char (2),
ultima_compra date,
primary key(cpf)
)default charset = utf8;
```

Ai estou tentei fazer o insert:

```
insert into pessoas values
('04496332780', 'João da Silva', '25-11-1969', 'Rua Antônio Numes', '88045963', 'Palmeiras','Londrina', 'PR','24-04-2018');
```

Pensei que pudesse ser algum erro por não ter descrito os campos ai tentei dessa forma:

```
insert into pessoas (cpf, nome, nascimento, endereco, cep, bairro, cidade, uf) values
('04496332780', 'João da Silva', '25-11-1969', 'Rua Antônio Numes', '88045963', 'Palmeiras','Londrina', 'PR','24-04-2018');
```

Mas o resultado foi o mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Na sua instrução SQL na descrição dos campos há 8 campos `"cpf, nome, nascimento, endereco, cep, bairro, cidade, uf)`" e no local dos valores há 9 valores "`('04496332780', 'João da Silva', '25-11-1969', 'Rua Antônio Numes', '88045963', 'Palmeiras','Londrina', 'PR','24-04-2018');"`. Está faltando a descrição do campo `ultima_compra` na descrição dos campos.

A instrução SQL deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
insert into pessoas (cpf, nome, nascimento, endereco, cep, bairro, cidade, uf, ultima_compra) values ('04496332780', 'João da Silva', '25-11-1969', 'Rua Antônio Numes', '88045963', 'Palmeiras','Londrina', 'PR','24-04-2018');
```